# jsonpath predicate filter not working in java

Tags: java, json, filter, jsonpath

I am using com.jayway.jsonpath 2.2.0 to see if attributes are in a series of JSON records.

Here's an example of a JSON record being used

```
{
    "data": 
    {
        "sampleTime": "2017-06-02T11:47:37.040Z",
        "target": 
        {
            "gateway": "TEST1",
            "probe": "zeus",
            "managedEntity": "zeus",
            "type": "",
            "sampler": "HARDWARE",
            "dataview": "HARDWARE",
            "filter": 
            {
                "osType": "Linux",
                "pluginName": "HARDWARE"
            }
        },

        "name": "cpuUtilisation",
        "row": 
        {
            "Value": "50.39 % (average load)"
        }
    },

    "operation": "update"
}
```

So I want to match if osType == 'Linux', see in the above record

I have some code that tries to do this and *seems* to work

```
@Test
public void test_jsonpath_filter_find_match() throws Exception {

    // load in json record from file
    String jsonString = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("resources/geneos-raw.table-cpuutilisation.json"), "UTF-8");

    List<Map<String, Object>> match  = JsonPath.parse(jsonString).read("$..filter", Filter.filter(Criteria.where("osType").eq("Linux")));

    System.out.println("result>" + match);
}
```

I get result printed that seems to prove the JSON record matches the filter

```
2017/06/03 09:01:27.216 [DEBUG][com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath]: Evaluating path: $..['filter']
result>[{"osType":"Linux","pluginName":"HARDWARE"}]
```

However, if I put a non-matching filter I still get the same result.

Note the osType == 'Windows' in the filter

```
@Test
public void test_jsonpath_filter_find_match() throws Exception {

    // load in json record from file
    String jsonString = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("resources/geneos-raw.table-cpuutilisation.json"), "UTF-8");

    List<Map<String, Object>> match  = JsonPath.parse(jsonString).read("$..filter", Filter.filter(Criteria.where("osType").eq("Windows")));

    System.out.println("result>" + match);
}
```

And the result is a match!

```
2017/06/03 09:02:06.137 [DEBUG][com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath]: Evaluating path: $..['filter']
result>[{"osType":"Linux","pluginName":"HARDWARE"}]
```

I believe the result should have been an empty List returned.

Is this a bug, or is there a flaw in my code/thinking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try filtering like this:

```
JsonPath.parse(jsonString).read("$..filter[?(@.osType=='Windows')]");
JsonPath.parse(jsonString).read("$..filter[?(@.osType=='Linux')]");
```

Comment: Ah yes, I should say - using $..filter[?(@.osType=='Linux')]  does work.

I specifically wanted to use the Filter and Criteria as it allows more complex filtering to be built using and, or & not.
One thing I couldn't seem to get working using the syntax suggested was negation, so filtering everything except Linux

Comment: Hmm, actually this works for negation, not sure why I didn't try it earlier!

List<Map<String, Object>> match  = JsonPath.parse(jsonString).read("$..filter[?(@.osType!='Windows')]");

I think I'll do as you suggested, it just seems odd why Filter and Criteria didn't seem to work

Comment: The code behind this came from http://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-jayway-jsonpath - I have a ticket open with Baeldung as to why Filter/Criteria isn't working properly. If I get a fix I'll post it here.

However your response does solve the issue, so I'll mark it as Accepted - thanks

Comment: @liamj Were you able to get the fix using the Filter and Criteria? I am still having this issue in version 2.5.0